# Can "attrib" of nosetests work with "__init__()" function in Python

Tags: python, function, init, attr, nose

I have a simple Python class here which has 3 functions. "test_a" (attr=slow),  "test_b" (attr=fast) and **init**(). The print statement in **init**() does not get called irrespective of whether I use "attr" in it or not. How can I have **init**() also called? Or is it even possible to do it with nosetests?

```
from testconfig import config as c
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

class TestMe(object):

    @attr(speed='slow')
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am inside init of test_me"

    @attr(speed='slow')
    def test_a(self):
        assert 'c' == 'c'
        print "I am here_a"

    @attr(speed='fast')
    def test_b(self):
        assert 'c' == 'c'
        print "I am here_b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__` isn't a test, so `nosetests` ignores the attribute. That function must run in order to instatiate the class in order to run `test_b`. I think you are not seeing the output because you aren't running `nosetests` with the `-s` option. Here's the output I get with that option and setting `speed` to "fast":

```
% nosetests -s -a speed=fast tmp.py
I am inside init of test_me
I am here_b
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks. -s option is cool! never checked that out! but now i did.. never too late!